# Is it possible to use MLJar for making clustering model?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, mljar

AFAIK, clustering is in unsupervised learning category, and also AFAIK MLJar is supervised. Is it correct to say that it is NOT supposed nor possible to use MLJar for making a clustering model? If I`m wrong, can you please show me a sample code about clustering using MLJar?
Edit:
I have found https://mljar.com/automated-machine-learning/k-means-features/, but I think it is usable only for preprocessing phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. K-means features are only used in preprocessing to add new features. In some datasets it helps to get better results.

MLJAR AutoML right now supports only supervised methods. I would love to extend it to unsupervised learning in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Keep on the good work!